# ConfigureAwait(true) is working only on 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, thread-local-storage

I ran following code on Dot Net Framework 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2 and 4.6

```
    public async Task<int> PrintCulturesAsync()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-IN");

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);

        await SomeMethod().ConfigureAwait(true);

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);

        return 1;
    }
```

I observed that Only on Framework 4.6, C`onfigureAwait(true)` is working and showing the same culture after `await SomeMethod().ConfigureAwait(true)` is called. 
Is it not supported on 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 ?

Comment: And what's the current synchronization context when you're calling this method?  Also note that it's entirely possible for a single synchronization context to use entirely different threads to handle different posts.  Some implementations will use one thread, and some won't.

Comment: For this example, I don't care about synchnization context (As this code can be in Windows, ASp.NET application). I got confuse since msdn document state that ConfigureAwait() is available for 4.5 and 4.6. But as Nitram pointed out "Starting with desktop apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6, the culture of the thread that creates and invokes a task becomes part of the thread's context" that's why it is working as expected on 4.6 only.

Answer (score 5):

That is a new feature in the .NET Framework 4.6

See: [Task Class (System.Threading.Tasks)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Starting with desktop apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6, the culture of the thread that creates and invokes a task becomes part of the thread's context. That is, regardless of the current culture of the thread on which the task executes, the current culture of the task is the culture of the calling thread. For apps that target versions of the .NET Framework prior to the .NET Framework 4.6, the culture of the task is the culture of the thread on which the task executes. For more information, see the "Culture and task-based asynchronous operations" section in the CultureInfo topic. Note that Store apps follow the Windows Runtime in setting and getting the default culture.

So the newly spawned tasks get the same culture as the thread that does the spawning.